# How do I remove the extra 'garbage' from this logfile?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm having some issues with log files from IIS 8.5 which I want to process with AWstats. Since my IIS servers are behind a load balancer I had to add a custom logging field, X-FORWARDED-FOR.
However, this ends up kinda messy in the log files:

```
2015-04-10 11:34:52 20000004f+OriginalIP+66.249.67.21+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 11:35:31 20000004f$OriginalIP+127.0.0.1,+136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 11:35:31 20000004f$OriginalIP+127.0.0.1,+136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01  [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 20000004f%OriginalIP+10.10.1.7,+89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 20000004f%OriginalIP+10.10.1.7,+89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 21:06:49 20000004f+OriginalIP+2.150.2.19+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
```

I can't get a hold of the load balancer guys/gals right now, so for now I'd like to fix it quick/dirty by doing a search/replace which turns all these '20000000f+OriginalIP+10.20.30.40+' entries into '10.20.30.40'.

updated: apparently there were more variations than i originally thought...

Answer (score 2):

This takes care of everything but one trailing `+`:

```
sed 's/ [^+ ]*+*\([0-9.]*\)[,+]*/ \1 /2' <<\IN
2015-04-10 11:35:31 20000004f$OriginalIP+127.0.0.1,+136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 11:35:31 20000004f$OriginalIP+127.0.0.1,+136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01  [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 20000004f%OriginalIP+10.10.1.7,+89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 20000004f%OriginalIP+10.10.1.7,+89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
IN
```

It prints...

```
2015-04-10 11:35:31 127.0.0.1 136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 11:35:31 127.0.0.1 136.243.19.46+ HV-WEB-01  [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 10.10.1.7 89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
2015-04-10 21:05:38 10.10.1.7 89.221.243.229+ HV-WEB-01 [etc]
```

Its because the fields are strung together on the characters I want to use as delimiters. It's a little frustrating, to be honest. But easily fixed:

```
sed 's/ [^+ ]*+*\([0-9.]*\)[,+]*/ \1 /2;s/+ / /' <infile
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much  :) 
 
But... I see I forgot to mention that in case of multiple IP's, I only need the last/public one...

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/20000000f+OriginalIP+\([0-9.]*\)+/\1/' <yourlog >newlog`

assuming that `yourlog` is the log you want to modify.  The modified log will be stored in `newlog`.

Comment: That worked like a charm  :)

Until I discovered there was a lot more variations in the log entries than I originally thought...  :-/
I've updated the question to clearify the issue.